# Сказал(,) («)сегодня(»)(,) (—) значит(,) сегодня

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, кавычки, связка, вводное-слово

***Сказал(,) («)сегодня(»)(,) (—) значит(,) сегодня.***

Как расставить знаки препинания? Нужно ли ставить «сегодня» в кавычки? Или ставить перед этим же словом запятую (потому что подразумевается: *Сказал, **что** сегодня*)? И интересно, как выделить значит — то ли как связку, то ли как вводное слово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Сказал, сегодня — значит, сегодня.***

Это БСП, смысл, к примеру, такой:  ***Если** я сказал, что нужно сделать сегодня, **то это значит,** что нужно сделать сегодня.*

Тире обозначает условно-следственные отношения в БСП (как в СПП): ***ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ***.

В первой части запятая обозначает **изъяснительные** отношения.

***Значит*** — вводное слово.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148744/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.